# NetworkOnMainThreadException while getting address from geocoder google API

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines, reverse-geocoding

I'm trying to get address from lat/lng using Google geocoder API, getting some random crashes, here  are the logs for the crash

```
Fatal Exception: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException:
       at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1952)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1910)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1860)
       at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.getFromLocation(ILocationManager.java:949)
       at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:133)
       at com.ui.activities.map.MapViewModel$getAddress$1.invokeSuspend(MapViewModel.kt:21)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:367)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(BuildersKt.java:1)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:47)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(BuildersKt.java:1)
       at com.ui.activities.map.MapViewModel.getAddress(MapViewModel.kt:19)
       at com.ui.activities.MapActivity.reload(MapActivity.java:1275)
       at com.ui.activities.MapActivity.onMapReady(MapActivity.java:1259)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzat.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:5)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzb.onTransact(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:3)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:667)
       at fd.c(fd.java:2)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bg.run(bg.java:1)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Here is my solution, calling geocoder getlocation from inside coroutine, but still getting some crashes,

```
fun getAddress(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
    val geocoder = Geocoder(app, Locale.getDefault())
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1)  
            addressObserver.value = addresses
        }catch (ex: Exception){
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `viewModelScope.launch()` will default to using `Dispatchers.Main.immediate`. You should specify your own dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

A coroutine launched from viewModelScope runs on the Main dispatcher by default.

In your case, as far as I know, there are two options to solve this:

1. `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {}` should be used.
2. Keep using `viewModelScope.launch {}` and wrap the `getFromLocation()` inside `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {}`